# Help with DateTime in format I need

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I am working with DateTime, trying to get date in the format like this:

`03.05.2010-04.05.23` that is: `dd.MM.yyyy-HH.mm.ss`

I'm using `DateTime.ParseExact` to try to achieve this (maybe wrong)

So far I have:

```
var dateInFormat = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), "dd.MM.yyyy.HH.mm.ss", null);
```

But can't quite get exactly what I want. Basically I want to keep the 0, for example time is 05:03:20 PM I don't want it to show like 5:3:20 PM

Any ideas?

Comment: purpose is time stamping for files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a date as DateTime (not string) then you can format it as leppie indicates:

```
  string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy-HH.mm.ss");
```

If on the other hand you have a date as string in the format `dd.MM.yyyy-HH.mm.ss` then you can use

```
 string mydate = "03.05.2010-04.05.23";
 DateTime dateFromString = DateTime.ParseExact(mydate, "dd.MM.yyyy-HH.mm.ss", null);
```

you get the exception because your string has the wrong format (namely the systems short date format)-

Comment: Actually I am just trying to Parse the time "right now" into that format, which is why I used `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: @baron: you seem to be confusing the terms. Parsing usually means taking a string and obtaining structured data from it (like a DateTime). If you start with a DateTime (what you get from DateTime.Now), you're not parsing.

Comment: but i'm still trying to turn that data into a different format - not sure whether my format keeps it still as DateTime I think it probably does ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any problem just using `ToString()`? Eg:

```
Console.WriteLine(dateInFormat.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy-HH.mm.ss"));
```

Comment: sorry, I should've explained, actually it crashes on that line: `FormatException`: String not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: Should'nt if be `DateTime.Now.ToString(...)`?

Comment: @Jens: any DateTime will do, wont it?

Comment: @baron: Your parsing string is different from what you have. Notice the missing `-`.